# Issue with Emacs theme

Tags: emacs

I'm new here. I've got some problems with setting theme to my emacs23, on Debian. I generated code with [Emac Theme Editor](http://jasonm23.github.io/emacs-theme-editor/). I created `~/.emacs.d/color-theme/bajka.el` 
file with this: http://wklej.org/id/1066433/

Then I added to my `~/.emacs`:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-bajka)
```

When I open Emacs, I see: *Cannot open load file, color theme*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have not installed the [color-theme package](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/). You'll also want to have `~/.emacs.d/color-theme` on your Emacs `load-path`.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "color-theme" user-emacs-directory))
```

Comment: I installed this package and now I can set theme from this package, but my own does't work. Error: Symbol's function definition is void: color-theme-bajka

Comment: My guess is that you've not updated your `load-path` as I already suggested. Have a look at its value (`C-h v RET load-path`).

Comment: I tried many times with load-path but it didn't help. I put code into .emacs and it is working. Thanks for effort.